# Displaying content error after changing the content in a navigator.pushed page

Tags: flutter

I am using the navigator pushed page to change data to null which its value is used in the build function of the parent page. Therefore whenever I pop out of the page, the getter function called on null error occurs. Is there any way I can avoid this error? Here is my code of the parent page, I would indicate the concerned part using comment:

```
  Widget accountTiles(BuildContext context) {
    firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
//settingsTile to be shown when User logged out
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      return SettingsTile(
        title: 'Login',
        onTap: () {...}, 
      );
    } else {
//the calling offirebaseUser.displayName is the cause of the error
      var displayNameAPP = firebaseUser.displayName;
      displayNameAPP ??= 'defaultName';
//SettingsTile that display the name and also navigate to the name changing page
      return SettingsTile(
        title: firebaseUser.email,
        subtitle: displayNameAPP + ', click here to change display name',
        leading: Icon(Icons.account_box),
        onTap: () {
          _changeDisplayName(context);
        },
      );
    }
  }
  Future<void> _changeDisplayName(BuildContext context) async {
    final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    await navigator
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChangeNamePage()));
  }
```

In the ChangeNamePage, after changing the name, the user would be logged out.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('New Display Name'),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        TextField(
          controller: displaynameController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'display name',
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
//the displayName is updated
            firebaseUser.updateProfile(
                displayName: displaynameController.text.trim());
//the user sign out here, therefore firebaseUser in parent page become null, and the call of displayName result in the error
            context.read<AuthenticationService>().signOut();
//going back to parent page
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Submit'),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Is there any way that even if I change a value used in parent page to null, but the parent page would notice that and switch into 'settingsTile to be shown when User logged out'